# Access object variables after object added to a queue?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to see how i would go about getting the Customer objects name and food, when it is already added to a queue? So say i'd like to print a string using from the name and food elements of the first customer object after its been added to the queue? The queue peek methods are place holders because I'm not sure how to access the object's name and food after it's been added to the queue. If i print the peek method, it just gives me the memory location, not the object food or name.

Result would be something like this:

"What do you want to process: pizza or salad?

salad

James’s salad is done!"

Code:

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File customerTxt = new File("customer.txt");
        Queue<Customer> pizza = new LinkedList<Customer>();
        Queue<Customer> salad = new LinkedList<Customer>();
        try {
            Scanner readCus = new Scanner(customerTxt);
            Scanner readFood = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (readCus.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = readCus.nextLine();
                String[] strArray = line.split(",");
                String customerName = strArray[0];
                String customerFood = strArray[1];
                Customer cus = new Customer(customerName, customerFood);
                if (customerFood.equalsIgnoreCase("salad")) {
                    salad.add(cus);
                }
                if (customerFood.equalsIgnoreCase("pizza")) {
                    pizza.add(cus);
                }
            }
            if (pizza.isEmpty() == false && salad.isEmpty() == false) {
                System.out.println("What kind of food would you like to make?");
                String foodChoice = readFood.nextLine();
                if (foodChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("salad")) {
                    System.out.println(salad.peek());
                }
                if (foodChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("pizza")) {
                    System.out.println(salad.peek());
                }
            }
            if (pizza.isEmpty() == true && salad.isEmpty() == false) {
                System.out.println("There are no Pizzas left to process. I will just finish the rest of the Salads");
                while (salad.isEmpty() == false) {
                    System.out.println(salad.peek());
                }
            }
            if (pizza.isEmpty() == false && salad.isEmpty() == true) {
                System.out.println("There are no Salads left to process. I will just finish the rest of the Pizzas");
                while (pizza.isEmpty() == false) {
                    System.out.println(pizza.peek());
                }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer {

    public String name = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String food = "";

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public Customer(String customerName, String customerFood) {
        this.name = customerName;
        this.food = customerFood;
    }



    }
```

Comment: Override `toString()` in the Customer class to include the food and name values

Comment: On a side note, it's quite ugly to find `<boolean value> == false` when `! <boolean value>` would be just fine. Maybe that's just me, but I think you should change your `pizza.isEmpty() == false && salad.isEmpty() == false` into `! pizza.isEmpty() && ! salad.isEmpty()` or `!(pizza.isEmpty() || salad.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `LinkedList.peek()`, it does return the correct object. I believe you just see the object's hash because you print the `Customer` object, which has not redefined `.toString()` : you are using `Object.toString()` which returns the hash you are seeing.

Either redefine `.toString()` in `Customer` as suggested by Zack Macomber if you always want to represent your `Customer` as its name and food choice, or instead choose to `System.out.println(queue.peek().getName() + " choosed " + queue.peek().getFood())` or something similar.